# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

estoy intentando compilar una aplicación de IOS, por medio de cocoa añadí los pods de firebase. Al intentar compilar me aparece el siguiente error:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___isPlatformVersionAtLeast", referenced from:
      -[APMMeasurement reportFirstOpenOnWorkerQueue] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement_a8dd8f414f0ab852dc536b0b90fa0992.o)
      -[APMSqliteStore prepareSQL:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMSqliteStore_0a821c4f08ef1829b8739ff30ad1cffe.o)
      +[APMASIdentifierWrapper iOS14OrAbove] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMASIdentifierWrapper_956b262b08898320f48bad82f10343ac.o)
      -[APMIdentity supportsAppTrackingConsentStatus] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMIdentity_b7c26fbe35850ccea06a684a0c94fc8f.o)
      _APMInAppPurchaseEventParametersFromProductAndTransactionV2 in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMInAppPurchaseTransaction_edea9bd715422e955ddab49b1cc6b62c.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

No sé que lo puede estar generando. Alguien tiene alguna idea?

Comment: Está abriendo el archivo .xcworkspace?

Comment: Sí. también probé reinstalar todos los pods y limpiar el caché.

Comment: Puedes agregar en la pregunta el código del PodFile?

Answer (score 1):

Estas usando la version de XCode incorrecta, isPlatformVersionAtLeast es parte del SDK iOS 13. Por lo que solo te va a funcionar con la version de XCode 11 o superior.

Asegurate de actualizar tu XCode a la version 11, eso deberia solucionar tu problema